# Is there a way to get TLS handshake data on the client side?

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

is there a way to access the TLS Handshake information on the client side like:

E.g.:

- pre-master key
- DH parameters
- server digital signature
- derived session key etc?

I created a simple server:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":44044", "./server/server.ecdsa.crt", "./server/server.ecdsa.key", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

and try to connect to it with this simple client:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                VerifyConnection: func(state tls.ConnectionState) error {
                    fmt.Println(state)
                    return nil
                },

            },
        },
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://localhost:44044/hello", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

As you can see I'm exploring the information I got from the `VerifyConnection` callback. However, I don't see a way to access information that I listed above.

I'm especially interested in any digital signature information from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Keys and secrets may be retrieved by setting the [tls.config.KeyLogWriter](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config.KeyLogWriter). There is an example snippet there as well. It is not recommended in production as it may leak secrets, but configuring a memory based io.Writer might make sense depending on your use case.

Isn't the server's certificate information available in VerifyPeerCertificate callback under the ConnectionState.PeerCertificates? Alternately, tls.Config.VerifyPeerCertificate receives the raw Certs and verified chains, which should have the information you're looking for.